# Azure ARM API to find Available VM size/sku for a given subscription and region

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-resource-manager

How to get the list of VM size/sku available for a given subscription and region using ARM api?

I found online one ARM API - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachinesizes/list

But it is not giving correct data as per requirement.

You can check the attached image. This api return list of both VM sizes (1) available ones (with black color in image) (2) not available ones (grayed out in image) and no field to distinguish them.

where as I need a list the only available VMs Or at least some flag in record which shows whether sku size is enabled or not.

[image]

Comment: can you try this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/compute/virtualmachinescalesets/listskus

Comment: we are not using scale-set, our system needs deployment of independent VM(/s). There should be some way without it as well, as you can see in attached image for independent VM creation portal is able to highlighted available VMs and disable unavailable ones.